# Tamaño de include en ScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Primero gracias de antemano, mi problema es que estoy haciendo un ScrollView y en este ScrollView he puesto un include y un texto debajo en el inlude pongo un layout y quiero que este layout ocupe la pantalla entera dentro del ScrollView como una pantalla principal y que deslizando puedas acceder a mas información y no se como hacerlo.

He pensado en obtener el tamaño de la pantalla y darle dicha dimensión al include para que los elementos se adapten a como lo tengo puesto pero el problema es que no se cambiar el tamaño del inlcude por código ya que no tiene las propiedades de un botón como el setWidth. Si alguien sabe como cambiar el tamaño del iclude con código o una manera mas rápida de hacerlo me ayudaría muchas gracias

Por cierto ya he probado a usar el fillViewport

adjunto codigo por si es de utilidad

activity main:

```
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include_tag"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/weather_main_screen"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:text="At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

layout implementado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Location"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cloudy_day" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/temperatureInfo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp" />


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/card"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="20dp" />

    </GridLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

codigo para obtener tamaño de pantalla:

```
class ScreenSize (Activity: Activity){


    fun Activity.DataCollector(): Pair<Int,Int>{

        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()

        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

        var width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        var height = displayMetrics.heightPixels


        return Pair(width,height)
    }
```

En el MainActivity no he puesto nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si es de ayuda para otros se puede hacer obteniendo el tamaño de la pantalla y cambiando el tamaño del include

```
// Gets the  size of screen
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()

    windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

    var width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
    var height = displayMetrics.heightPixels





    // Gets the include 
    val include: View = findViewById(R.id.include_tag)
    // Gets the include view params that will allow you to resize the layout
    val params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = include.layoutParams
    params.width = width
    params.height = height
    include.layoutParams = params
```